# How to exclude a system attribute (SKU, Description..) from a search?

Tags: attributes, search

As the title, I would like to exclude a system attribute (SKU, Description..) from a search.
I've tried setting to 'NO' the 'Use in Quick Search' and the 'Use in Advanced Search' fields in the 'Frontend Properties' but it seems it doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you reindex after changing the the attributes settings?

Comment: Yes Marius, I did it.

Answer (score 3):

Go to
`Catelog->Attributes->manage Attribute`
and click on attribute which you want to edit

Now you can see to types of setting for attributes **Back-End and front End**.

In front end section you got options for **Use in Quick Search**, **Use in Advanced Search** etc.

You can configure your product attribute as you wanted:)

Comment: Hi Charlie,
I've just written that **I've tried** your suggestion and it doesn't work!